# jQuery concatenating int and string in id selector

Tags: php, jquery, click

I have a bunch of table cells named thus:

```
for($x=0;$x<20;$x++){
            echo "<td id='td"; echo $x; echo "'>";
                        //put some text in the cell...
                    echo "</td>";

}
```

i.e. each cell's id is td0,td1,td2...
The table looks ok. Now I want to make it clickable (cell-wise) with jQuery.

I tried as a test case:

```
$("#td0").click(function(){        
  $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
  //do some other stuff...

});
```

This worked fine. The first cell is clickable.
Now I want to use a for-loop to make each cell clickable:

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    cell = "#td"+i;
    $(cell).click(function(){
                 //stuff...
        });
}
```

This doesn't work for any cell. I'm not sure why, or how to fix it. Any help appreciated.

EDIT

Sorry I should have mentioned, the function will be different depending on the cell (e.g. click td0 will have very different action to clicking td8, say), so I can't just use a generic "td", I don't think.

Comment: why don't you assign an id to your table and use something like $("#my_table td").click(function() { ... });

Comment: Any time you write "...doesn't work..." in a technical question, backspace over it and say ***exactly*** what you expect it to do, what it's doing instead, and why you think that isn't right. Separately: I wouldn't do it that way, but your `for` loop at the end should "work" in that it would set up event handlers on the cells.

Comment: Using event delegation or giving the cells a common class and select the class would be a better solution. *edit:* *"the function will be different depending on the cell"*, then why do you use a loop? Loops are used to execute *the same* code multiple times, i.e. in your case, bind *the same* function.

Comment: *"Sorry I should have mentioned, the function will be different depending on the cell...so I can't just use a generic "td", I don't think."* You can, you just have to branch within the event handler function based on what cell was clicked.

Comment: I've updated my answer to incorporate your slight question change. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cheapest way to go around it would be to add a class and only use 1 binding function.

```
for($x=0;$x<20;$x++){
        echo "<td class='table-cell' id='td" . $x . "'>";

        //put some text in the cell...
        echo "</td>";

}
```

Now bind it to click and check for the id of clicked

```
$(".table-cell").click(function(e){        
    $(e.target.id).css("background-color","yellow");
    //do some other stuff...

});
```

Or you can use a switch in bind

```
$(".table-cell").click(function(e){        

    switch(e.target.id)
    {
    case 1:
      //execute code block 1
      break;
    case 2:
      //execute code block 2
      break;
    default:
      //code to be executed for default
    }

});
```

Comment: You don't need to use echo multiple times. You can simply add $x to the string by doing 
    `echo '<td id="whatever" data-value="' . $x . '">';`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly lolz. My bad. I did not even look at what he was trying to print after id.

Comment: Yeah that was directed at @JJG's initial question, but as he accepted this one I figured I'd point it out here :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td[id^="td"]').click(function() { ... })
```

Edit: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bUsKp/1/).

Edit (question changed slightly): [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bUsKp/2/).

```
$('td[id^="td"]').click(function() {
    var tdVal = $(this).attr('id').replace('td', '');
    switch (tdVal) { ... }
})
```

I think you may be better off using a data-* attribute to represent the value, however:

```
<td class="myTableCell" data-value="0"></td>
<td class="myTableCell" data-value="1"></td>

$('td.myTableCell').click(function() {
    var tdVal = $(this).attr('data-value');
    ...
})
```

Edit: [Final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bUsKp/3/).

...and with the PHP (no need to use echo so many times):

```
for($x=0;$x<20;$x++){
        echo "<td id='td' data-value='" . $x . "'>";
                    //put some text in the cell...
                echo "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td[id^="td"]').click(function(){        
  $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
  //do some other stuff...

});
```